# Why is according to the law of sines $sinA=\frac{a}{2R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

**question**
Why is according to the law of sines $sinA=\frac{a}{2R}$

**...**
i understand the law of sines but I do not understand how this is possible, i need an explanation of where the radius came from

*reminder*
R is the radius of a circumcircle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The law of sines says that ($d$ - diameter of circumcircle)
$$\frac a {\sin A} =\frac b {\sin B} =\frac c {\sin B} = d $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac {\sin A} {a} = \frac 1 d $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sin A = \frac a d = \frac a {2r} $$

Comment: why downvote? the law of sine is exactly this...

Comment: I suppose it is known what a diameter and a radius are

Comment: yeah its right @qwerty

Comment: whoever is downvoting: he just needed an arithmetical derivation not a proof of the law of sines

Answer (score 2):

You just need to see the proof of law of sines. See [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie25b588XQAhUBKY8KHYvRDAAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLaw_of_sines&usg=AFQjCNEThu7vgMYsBBO_qzOISKQIMhvr5w) Or you just take a look at this picture:[image]

Comment: he just needed an arithmetical derivation not a proof of the law of sines

Comment: He asked where the radius come from?? And I showed him what he wanted.

Comment: By the way, I am not the one who downvoted.

Comment: i did not say you were. I just think his question is worded poorly

Comment: Yes, I agree. he had incomplete knowledge.